# BootStrap Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xrhzchsr/) sample of my alert in click event button. I manage to search code that after the event the alert will be fade out. What I want to do now is the `div` of my button will not be affected `before and after` the click event. What I mean in affected is

1. before click - the button must have a space for the alert to be view
2. after click - the button must not move upward after the alert fade.

I hope you guys understand it.

*Newbie here in bootstrap.*

**CODE**

***CSHTML***

```
 < div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert" style="width:auto">
 <strong>Success! </strong >
 < /div >

 < div class="modal-footer" >
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">
        Alert</button >
 < /div >
```

**JS**

```
 $("#success-alert").hide();
$("#btnAlert").click(function () {
    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(5000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
The reason the space above keeps disappearing is that there's no element to consume that space so the button moves upwards.So here I just set the opacity of the html above the button to zero.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nilerafter24/6z3fzud8/)

```
 $("#success-alert").css("opacity","0");
    $("#btnAlert").click(function () {
            $("#success-alert").css("opacity","1");
        $("#success-alert").fadeTo(5000, 500,function(){
         $("#success-alert").css("opacity","0");
        });       
    });
```

Comment: **EDIT**.. In first load how do i set the button like that?